# ffmpeg for php and how to reduce noise

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have an audio wav file (1-7 sec) and need to reduce noise or just make background volume down, in PHP maybe by using ffmpeg.
Also after reduce bg, is it possible to trim free spaces of sound at begining and end of audio?

Is there any way for these things?

Comment: What did you try ? And btw checkout http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html !

Comment: i record some voice and then need to remove background, or just reduce it.